# Map an object to a hash with Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud, spring-data-redis

Say I have a User class

```
class User {
    private Long id
    private String username
    private String password
}
```

I read a few articles/tutorials regarding storing repositories with redis in hash.

However they all have one key for the whole "table", what put into redis looks like following:

```
user 1 {id:1,username:'',password:''}
user 2 {id:1,username:'',password:''}
```

they all had `id` as the `hash key` in this case.

What I wanted to achieve is to use each `field` as a `hash key`, like below:

```
user:1 id 1
user:1 username ''
user:1 password ''
```

And after quite a lot of time searching, I found `Jackson2HashMapper` could be the help. But there is no articles/documentations on how to use this mapper exactly.

Have anyone else faced similar situations?

Comment: What was the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294485/6309 that you just deleted?

Comment: @VonC it turns out you should avoid setting header 'X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url' in nginx

Comment: Great! adding that as an answer and accepting it would help others with the same problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

i just use like this:

```
@Bean
public HashMapper<Object, byte[], byte[]> hashMapper() {
    return new ObjectHashMapper();
}

@Component
public class HashMapping<T> {
    @NonNull
    private StringRedisTemplate                stringRedisTemplate;
    @NonNull
    private HashMapper<Object, byte[], byte[]> hashMapper;

    public void writeHash(String key, T t) {
        checkNotNull(key, "hash key cannot be null");
        checkNotNull(t, "hash value cannot be null");
        stringRedisTemplate.execute((RedisCallback<Void>) connection -> {
            Map<byte[], byte[]> mappedHash = hashMapper.toHash(t);
            connection.hMSet(key.getBytes(), mappedHash);
            return null;
        });
    }

    public T loadHash(String key) {
        checkNotNull(key, "hash key cannot be null");
        Map<byte[], byte[]> loadedHash = 
stringRedisTemplate.getConnectionFactory()
                .getConnection().hGetAll(key.getBytes());
        return (T) hashMapper.fromHash(loadedHash);
    }

}
```